# PrintWriter and LinkedList

Tags: java, printwriter, type-mismatch

I need to iterate through saved clients connections (on the server side) and send them messages (AS one people write a message - others connected should see it too).

I tried to do that:

```
for (PrintWriter out : connections) {
    out.println(message);
    out.flush();
}
```

`connections` is

```
LinkedList connections = new LinkedList();
```

But for the `for` loop I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to PrintWriter.
```

Could anyone help me or suggest another idea how to get done it. Thanks.

Comment: which type of values you want to store in LinkedList object

Comment: Linked List is only a collection , you should tell it the type , like how you say `int[]` , an array of type integer , similarly give LinkedList a type parameter such as `LinkedList<Integer>`, or `LinkedList<PrintWriter>` in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinkedList connections = new LinkedList();
```

is a raw type and thus it knows its elements as of the Type Object. You need to add a generic type paramter to it:

```
LinkedList<PrintWriter> connections = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
LinkedList connections = new LinkedList();
```

use

```
LinkedList<PrintWriter> connections = new LinkedList<PrintWriter>();
```

. This makes sure that you can only put `PrintWriter`s into the list, and when taking objects out of the list, the compiler is assured that the object taken out is a `PrintWriter`, and there will be no problem anymore.